# Float counting, Negative Zero?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am setting sound effect volume for my game. I want the volume to go from 0.0 to 1.0 by increments of 0.1.

However, when it reaches zero, my log instead tells me it is -0.00000 and continues counting down. Please tell me what is wrong. Thanks

```
-(void)sfxUp{
     NSLog(@"SFX UP %f",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"]);
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"] == 1.0f)
        return;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setFloat:([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"]+0.1f) forKey:@"sfx_volume"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"]];
    NSLog(@"SFX UP %f",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"]);
}
-(void)sfxDown{
    NSLog(@"SFX DOWN %f",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"]);
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"] == 0.0f)
        return;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setFloat:([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"]-0.1f) forKey:@"sfx_volume"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"]];
     NSLog(@"SFX DOWN %f",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"sfx_volume"]);
}
```

Clicking only the 'Volume Down' button, this is my log output:

```
2012-06-13 18:32:25.067 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:32:25.068 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.900000
2012-06-13 18:32:25.385 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.900000
2012-06-13 18:32:25.386 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.800000
2012-06-13 18:32:25.623 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.800000
2012-06-13 18:32:25.624 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.700000
2012-06-13 18:32:25.873 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.700000
2012-06-13 18:32:25.874 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.600000
2012-06-13 18:32:26.116 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.600000
2012-06-13 18:32:26.140 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.500000
2012-06-13 18:32:26.346 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.500000
2012-06-13 18:32:26.348 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.400000
2012-06-13 18:32:26.605 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.400000
2012-06-13 18:32:26.608 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.300000
2012-06-13 18:32:26.835 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.300000
2012-06-13 18:32:26.838 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.200000
2012-06-13 18:32:27.068 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.200000
2012-06-13 18:32:27.069 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.100000
2012-06-13 18:32:27.319 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN 0.100000
2012-06-13 18:32:27.338 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.000000
2012-06-13 18:32:27.630 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.000000
2012-06-13 18:32:27.640 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.100000
2012-06-13 18:32:27.946 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.100000
2012-06-13 18:32:27.947 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.200000
2012-06-13 18:32:28.170 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.200000
2012-06-13 18:32:28.172 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.300000
2012-06-13 18:32:28.414 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.300000
2012-06-13 18:32:28.416 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.400000
2012-06-13 18:32:28.641 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.400000
2012-06-13 18:32:28.643 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.500000
2012-06-13 18:32:28.869 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.500000
2012-06-13 18:32:28.870 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.600000
2012-06-13 18:32:29.301 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.600000
2012-06-13 18:32:29.303 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.700000
2012-06-13 18:32:29.584 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.700000
2012-06-13 18:32:29.586 Bomb Defuse[80558:1c403] SFX DOWN -0.800000
```

**EDIT:**

Changing to >= and <= (respectively) has the following output:

```
2012-06-13 18:45:34.574 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:35.135 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:35.529 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:35.877 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:36.057 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:36.229 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:36.391 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:36.542 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:36.717 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:36.897 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG UP 1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:37.599 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN1.000000
2012-06-13 18:45:37.602 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN0.900000
2012-06-13 18:45:38.431 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN0.900000
2012-06-13 18:45:38.491 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
2012-06-13 18:45:38.617 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
2012-06-13 18:45:38.951 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
2012-06-13 18:45:39.125 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
2012-06-13 18:45:39.479 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
2012-06-13 18:45:39.908 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
2012-06-13 18:45:40.399 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
2012-06-13 18:45:40.624 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
2012-06-13 18:45:40.841 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
2012-06-13 18:45:41.059 Bomb Defuse[80607:1c403] BG DOWN-0.100000
```

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: You should change `== 1.0` for `>= 1.0` and `== 0.0` for `<= 0.0`, and your program will work. You could also make your step `0.125`, then your exact comparisons would work.

Comment: What I think you are missing is the fact that your result isn't exactly `-0`. Instead, it's probably a value like `-0.0000000000000001`, but `NSLog` is truncating the value. Thus, you should always use `<=` or `>=` for floating point values, almost never `==`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact -- starting with 1.0 and subtracting 0.1 ten times will not necessarily give you exactly 0.0. For more details, read the classic paper [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

You can work around this by capping the value to `[0.0, 1.0]` when it is changed, by avoiding strict equality comparisons (e.g, use `>=` or `<=` instead of `==`), or -- ideally -- by simply storing the volume as an integer between 0 and 10, and dividing by 10.0 where needed.

Comment: Beat me to it! Also, it is showing -0.00000 because it is truncating to 0 for display, but from the negative side.

Comment: Also, note that floating point actually has two separate representations for positive and negative zero (32-bit IEEE754 representations 00000000 and 80000000). They compare as equal, but they are not identical.